# Adding a new Org to an existing Hyperledger Fabric network using the Fabric Node SDK

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, hyperledger-fabric

Here is where I am at the moment:

Fabric version 1.4.1
Using byfn.sh to create Org1, Org2, Orderer etc and bring the channel mychannel up
Language: Node using Typescript

I have followed the instructions in this tutorial to add a third org Org3 https://medium.com/@kctheservant/add-a-new-organization-on-existing-hyperledger-fabric-network-2c9e303955b2

This works great.

Now, I would like to add another Org but using the Fabric Node SDK. Is that possible?

Scenario is this:

1. A network admin logs into a custom UI being developed to manage a Fabric network.
2. The admin inputs details such as new Org name, MSP ID, peers info into the UI
3. The UI invokes a service layer which will

   1. Invoke a Fabric Node SDK API to create crypto materials for the new
      Org b.
   2. Invoke Fabric Node SDK API to create the new Org and have it
      join the channel mychannel
   3. Install chaincode to the new Org's peers d.
   4. Run some tests of invoke and query chaincode to ensure that the new Org can query and submit transactions

In the last step, I will save the new channel configuration and the new Org configuration to yaml or json files.

I have looked at the Node SDK and have seen the [Organization](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Organization.html) and [Channel](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Channel.html) methods. However, it seems like the Organization class is not exposed as a type for Typescript, so I am not sure how to use it.

It would help if someone could explain the methods I need to use to get to what I am trying to do.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the title of the article is misleading. In the article, you are adding a new org in the existing channel not in the network.

Please take a look at the official documentation. The same tutorial.
[Adding an Org to a Channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html)

For your requirement, yes we can do the same using the node sdk.

Check out this tutorial. [update channel config](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-channel-create.html)

In the tutorial, they are updating the channel id to create a new channel with that id.

You can use the same steps to update the organizations.

You have to run `shell` command using either by `shell.js` or `child-process`.

Hope it will clear your doubts.

Comment: Hi Shubham, thanks for the response. I had gone through these examples but wanted to know if I could execute all the steps by just using the Fabric Node SDK instead of having to use command line tools. For example, there is an Organization object and an MSP object in the SDK. I wanted to know if they can used to 1) Add a new org to an existing network and 2) Have it join an existing channel.

Comment: Also, I wanted to add that I have no issues using command line tools *if I have to* but I just wanted to know authoritatively whether everything could be done using the SDK APIs (could not find any examples on the internet for the same so I have asked in Fabric forums on hyperledger.org, posted a question on Hyperledger JIRA and asked here)

Comment: I also search for this a few months back and found no answer. All we require is binaries endpoint but, as per my knowledge, other than `configtxlator` no binaries expose APIs. By the time no APIs or any alternative introduce, we have to stick with the cli.

Comment: Hey, I tried searching for the source for configtxlator but was unable to find it. If we have source then we might be able to the same thing in the API. As far as I know, that is the only tool to build the channel config

Comment: For now, we need to rely on "child_process" library of node to execute configtxlator commands and as you know we have already covered every other steps with node sdk.

Comment: I am curious about the Organization object and the MSP object in Fabric Node SDK.  Can we not do something like "new Organization", then set its attributes (certs, private keys, name etc) and then add this using the Channel object? The assumption is that an existing admin is adding this new Org. For configtxlator type functions, can we not use getGenesisBlock and getChannelConfigFromOrderer? If this isn't possible, can someone explain why we cannot purely add a new organization using the Fabric Node SDK? I have not tried these methods yet and was really hoping someone had, but now I am curious

Comment: First, you have to understand, when we say a new org in the network, that means you have to add the org in the `genesis.block` which was created in the beginning. To get this block you have to access system channel, in the byfn it is `byfn-sys-channel`. From SDK we can access only custom channel which we create using SDK. There are no such methods which will return the `system-channel`. If you have to add a new org in the network then you have to use fabric-tools cli.

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar are you on Telegram? I would like to chat with you in regards to this. Please let me know. I am ashishchandr70 on Telegram.